# linux kernel when interrupt disabled and preempt enabled at the same time?

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt

What are the cases in the linux kernel when we need to have interrupt disabled and preempt enabled at the same time?

As far as I know, this state only exists during some transitions, for example, at the end of the interrupt handler and before preempt_schedule_irq() is called.